# Router Cannot See MAC Address of Devices Behind RPi Bridge

Tags: wifi, ethernet, bridge

I followed Option 1 (Same Subnet) of [this](https://www.willhaley.com/blog/raspberry-pi-wifi-ethernet-bridge/) tutorial to turn my Raspberry Pi into a WiFi-to-Ethernet Bridge. It works great, but the router cannot see the device connected behind the bridge as being connected. The IP Address of the Ethernet-connected TV I'm using shows up with the command 'arp -a' ran from my MacBook on the same network, but it is listed as having the same MAC Address as the Raspberry Pi. Is there a simple fix for the router to see the MAC Address of the device behind the bridge?

To sum up: the TV has internet access, but cannot see the other devices on my LAN.

Comment: Did you follow Option 1 or Option 2

Comment: @Jaromanda I followed Option 1: Same Subnet

Comment: @Milliways doesn't matter why I'm bridging, question clearly states I've setup a bridge and can't see MAC Addresses.